# How to type the props of a component that returns a Typography with component="h1"?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I made a utility component that returns an instance of a MUI/Material-UI Typography component with some defaults:

```
// type H1Props = WHAT SHOULD THIS BE?!?!

export const H1 = (props: H1Props) => <Typography component="h1" variant="h3" {...props} />;
```

This component is used as such:

```
<H1 role="heading" sx={{ m: 1 }}>Section Heading</H1>
```

I need to be able to add HTML attributes for an H1 element, like `role`, and Typography props like `sx`. How should I type the props? I've tried a number of things, nothing seems to work.

Comment: I had a look and these seem to be attributes that don't exist on the `Typography` component of MUI. Is that your problem? Or is the problem what the type should be of something like `role` and `sx`? If so, you'll first need to let us know what `role` and `sx` is (they could be multiple things).

Comment: `role` is an [HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) used here just as an example. It could've been `id`, `style` or anything else. `sx` is a [custom prop from the MUI style system](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) and is declared in the [TypographyTypeMap interface](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

Edit: TypographyProps -> TypographyTypeMap